# Why isn’t this building collapsing?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

Well the title pretty much says all I want to know.

I was just building around in my base and I tried to collapse a huge complex of a building. Destroying a key structure made the complex start collapsing as I'm used to it. But for some reason, this construct isn't giving much onto the ingame physics and decided to not collapse:

[image]

Is this a bug? Or is there any other known reason why this happened?

Comment: Do buildings collapse like that in Save the world? I've never noticed it in battle royale and haven't done much building in StW myself

Comment: @VanBuzzKill: Dunno, this never happened to me in battle royale. But since I mentioned this happened in **my base**, This actually IS save the world ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after some try and error research I did myself in my base I figured out, in the first base there is a soccer field right behind the Hills in the back of the base. This soccer field has a zone around it which doesnt let you build 3 tiles around it and 5 tiles under and above it.

This zone is apparently considered as constructions (or what ever the physic does behind the scene) so if buildings are in direct contact to the zone you can't build in, they seem to be considered as beeing attatched to something solid, and wont collapse therefor.

So everyone who dreamt of having a flying castle in his base, just attatch its "base" to that zone ;)